# Poset of degree zero bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, buildings

Let’s assume we are working on a smooth projective curve $X$. For any vector bundle $E$ on $X$, the poset of non-trivial proper sub-bundles of $E$ is in bijection with the poset of non-zero proper sub-spaces of the vector space $E_K$ ($E$ pulled back to the generic point) so it gives us the Tits building, which it’s reduced Homology is concentrated in one degree. Now assume $E$ is degree zero and we are only interested in degree zero sub-bundles. Is it possible to see whether the reduced Homology of this construction is concentrated in one degree or not? (The same proof for Tits building does not work, on the other I do not know a counter-example, in most cases it becomes contractible )